# Does the font name in Tesseract box/tif filenames matter?

Tags: tesseract

In the [Tesseract wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-%E2%80%93-Make-Box-Files) the format for labeled tif/box file filenames to be used in training is given as `[lang].[fontname].exp[num]`.  Does `fontname` actually impact training or is this just for bookkeeping?

In my particular case, I have a large number of document images with different fonts (and I don't know which fonts are in them).  Can I just use `eng.idontknow.exp[num]` for each document I label manually or will this mess up training for some reason?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to match a real font (to help possible post-OCR analyses), but it can be some arbitrary font name.